# CSS Navigation Sprite hover not working

Tags: html, css, hover, sprite

I have a problem while trying to implement the CSS part for my sprite navigation to bring the "hover" effect from my sprite on hover. Easier to explain if I show the code.

THE CSS:

```
#nav {

    width:837px;
    float:left;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 30px;
    background:url(../images/withtext.gif) repeat-x;
    height:79px;
    position: relative;
    top: -45px;
}   


#nav li {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 list-style-type:none;
 display:inline; 
 height:79px;
 text-align:center; 
 float:left; 
 line-height:79px; 
 font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 }



#nav a {
 display:block;
 height:79px; 
 color:#311f11;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-size:13px;
 }

#nav a:hover {
 background-image:url(withtext.gif); 
 color:#fff;
 }



#nav .snowboard { width:240px; }
#nav .snowboard a:hover { background-position: 0px bottom; }
```

The Html:

```
<ul id="nav">
   <li class="snowboard"><a href="#">Snowboard</a></li>
   <li class="briller"><a href="#">Briller</a></li>
   <li class="ski"><a href="#">Ski</a></li>
   <li class="stovler"><a href="#">Stovler</a></li>
   <li class="handlevogn"><a href="#">Handlevogn</a></li>

</ul>
```

Navigation image:

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7EzC.gif "Navigation bar with passive and hover state"

Current state of navigation:

[2] https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5Lia.jpg "Navigation in browser"

So how do I make it so that it moves down the image a Whole notch on hover ?

Help greatly appreciated in advance!

Comment: There we go, sorry about that.

Comment: Really noone that can answer this?

Comment: Oh sorry, thought it just went to page 10 and thats all..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here goes your working [solution](http://codepen.io/sonu/pen/ysoIC)

```
#nav ul, #nav li{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#nav {

    width:837px;
    float:left;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 30px;
    background:url(http://i.imgur.com/zkVmoEN.gif) repeat-x;
    height:79px;
    position: relative;
}   

#nav li {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 list-style-type:none;
 display:inline; 
 height:79px;
 text-align:center; 
 float:left; 
 line-height:79px; 
 font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 }

#nav a {
 display:block;
 height:79px; 
 color:#311f11;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-size:13px;
  width:150px;
  text-indent:-9999px;
 }
.snowboard a:hover {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/zkVmoEN.gif);
  background-position: -40px 80px;
}
.briller a:hover {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/zkVmoEN.gif);
  background-position: -190px 80px;
}
.ski a:hover {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/zkVmoEN.gif);
  background-position: -340px 80px;
}
.stovler a:hover {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/zkVmoEN.gif);
  background-position: -490px 80px;
}
.handlevogn a:hover {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/zkVmoEN.gif);
  background-position: -640px 80px;
}
```

Comment: And the solution it is! Thanks! Things all of a sudden moved all around and got a bit mixed, but the hover is at least working, I'll see what I can do about that. Sonu, could I possibly add you somewhere or message you for another follow-up question I have?

Comment: Fixed my position issue as well, thanks! Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
#nav li a {
 display:block;
 height:79px; 
 color:#311f11;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-size:13px;
 }

#nav li a:hover {
 background-image:url(withtext.gif); 
 color:#fff;
 }



#nav li.snowboard { width:240px; }
#nav li.snowboard a:hover { background-position: 0px -79px; }/*Here change as needed.*/
```

Css classes always use the tags eg.: `li.class{}`
Try to keep the selectors trading at the same level:

```
foo foo2 foo2 a{}
foo foo2 foo2 a:hover{}
```

In background-position use px negative and positive.

> **Note-OFF:** I recommend that if you have trouble making your css wheels
>   in various browsers, you try to use CSS RESET:
>
> *{
>     margin:0;
>     padding:0;
>     list-style-type:none;
>   }

Comment: this in the `image` is http://i.imgur.com/zkVmoEN.gif withtext.gif??
You have not declared correctly. Could put your code online?

Comment: I guess I could give the whole folder or something if that helps? With the Index, images and css.

Answer (score 1):

If you're having trouble with the CSS, it may be because you're only adding hover effects to the text. You can't hover the text and have a background image where you want by  the way. If you would like, you can try this:

CSS:

```
    #nav{background:url(../images/withtext.gif) 
    repeat-x;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    }
li {
background-color: #??????;
}
li a {
color: black;
}
li:hover {
background-color: #something_different;
}
li a:hover {
color:#something_different;
}
```

Or, if you want to have the li classes each different, you could just do this:

```
.snowboard li:hover {
Some code...
}

.snowboard li a:hover {
some code
}
```

If you're layout is like that, you can basically do anything.

Comment: I tried all the suggestions but it just won't work. Can it be that the issue is further up in my CSS? Because I have content text beneath my navigation menu. Can that be pushing it somehow? If you could add me on Skype Max or something like that I would highly appreciate it and rep you all the way.

Comment: My Skype is maximillianhk if you want to add me